# Issue with hooks when creating a NativeScript and Angular app template

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I’m attempting to create a new template for creating new NativeScript apps with Angular 2, very much like https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng.

Here’s the problem: for whatever reason after I create new apps with my template, I end up with two `hooks` folders—one in the root folder, and one in `app/`. The root `hooks` is cool, but `app/hooks/before-livesync/nativescript-angular-sync.js` causes TypeScript problems when I try to run the app I created from the template.

So here’s my question: why does `app/hooks` exist? It doesn’t when I create apps using `tns create test --ng` (which uses https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ng). I’m including the full `package.json` that I’m using below. Any help would be appreciated.

```
{
  "name": "tns-template-tutorial-ng",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A template for the NativeScript & Angular tutorial on nativescript.org",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/nativescript/tns-template-tutorial-ng.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "NativeScript"
  ],
  "author": "Telerik <support@telerik.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/nativescript/tns-template-tutorial-ng/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/nativescript/tns-template-tutorial-ng/groceries",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "3.1.2",
    "nativescript-angular": "1.1.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "tns-core-modules": "2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "0.6.21"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the way the TNS command behaves when it extracts out the template it applies certain actions a second time (improperly).

See the top part of: https://github.com/NativeScript/theme/issues/95 for a discussion of the issue.  The issue got swept unfortunately under the rug by the discussion on removing/leaving the post install script.   But the actual underlying issue is because the TNS does some weird things during its installation of the template which breaks things.